# Intro div on first load

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am creating a Vue 3 app using typescript and I want to create a "intro view" on website first load which disappears after I click the button. I am very new to Vue and especially TypeScript.

What I have done so far:

**HTML code**

```
<div id="splash" class="splash">
  <h1 class="fade-in">Hello</h1>
  <router-link to="/" @click="spashClose()">CLOSE</router-link>
</div>
```

**Vue code**

```
mounted() {
this.splashOpen();
},

methods: {
 splashOpen: function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('pageLoadCount') == '2') {
    var splash = document.getElementById('splash');
    splash.remove();
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('pageLoadCount', '1');
  }
},

spashClose: function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('pageLoadCount')) {
    localStorage.setItem('pageLoadCount', '2');
  }
 },
},
```

Actually, this way works fine (I guess). But I would like to achieve the same result by using `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})` as it seems better (if not, explain please). I was trying to put this code into the method and then into `mounted()` but this aproach didn't work out.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like you are trying to do vanilla javascript instead of using actual vue functionality - you could simply set a ```toggleSplash``` variable on mounted and display the splash with ```v-if=toggleSplash```.

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann Thank you for your reply. As I said, I am a real noob in Vue so I need more detailed explanation :) Could you please provide some?

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann and I don't need it to appear again after refresh or page redirection. It must to appear only when a user connects to website for the first time during the session. Make it appear and disappear is not that hard for me. Make it appear only once - is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider a more 'Vue' approach to doing this - simply set a variable value based on the result from your initial localstorage value, and then display the splashscreen depending on the variable value - something along those lines:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bash-ve5bv?file=/src/App.vue

With Vue you rarely need to do things like :

```
var splash = document.getElementById('splash');
splash.remove();
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I thought so, but lack of experience has led to a dead end. Thanks for your help buddy!